# python classes calculate sum and difference of two value

Tags: python-3.7

I should introduce two two function of the class and calculate difference and sum of them.

I wrote this code:

`class station:
    def __station(d1,d2,a,b)
    d1=int(input('temperature of first station: '))
    d2=int(input('temperature of second station: '))
    a=d1+d2
    b=d2-d1
    print('sum of temperature' ,a)
    print('difference of temperature',b)
    return`

but it does not run. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were several errors in the code:

- The indentation was incorrect
- The second line, being a function declaration, should have ended in a colon `:`

The were also several other problems with the code:

- It is Python convention that `class` names begin with a capital letter (so `Station`, not `station`)
- The return at the end of the function was completely redundant
- Are you sure you want to make the `__station` method private? (See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-methods-in-python/ and here: https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_private_attributes_methods.php for more information.)
- Why did your function accept the arguments `d1`, `d2`, `a` and `b`? All of the variables were defined within your function. Function arguments are for accepting input from outside the function
- Some linters will complain if `self` is not a parameter of `Station.station`

With all of the above in mind, here is the corrected version of your code:

```
class Station:
    def station(self):
        d1=int(input('temperature of first station: '))
        d2=int(input('temperature of second station: '))
        a=d1+d2
        b=d2-d1
        print('sum of temperature', a)
        print('difference of temperature', b)

# demonstrate usage:

# instantiate Station
my_station = Station()

my_station.station()
```

Comment: Thank you, But when I run this code it says:  "Method has no argument... pylint(no-method-argument)[2,5]."

Comment: If you want you can add `self` as a parameter to `station`. You will then have to write `Station().station()` instead of `Station.station()` i.e. you will have to instantiate the class to use it. I didn't mention this before because most systems will still let the code run regardless

Comment: Sorry, I changed station() in line 2 to Station().station() but it give syntax error